# Solving multi-objective model in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

Is there a command in GAMS to solve multi objective problem. 
How can I solve multi objective model by GAMS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See This
[SOLVING MULTI-OBJECTIVE MODELS WITH GAMS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwi89JjB1PffAhVHtYsKHYcRAtQQFjAAegQIChAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Ffile.PostFileLoader.html%3Fid%3D5885d81096b7e4e73d5fe443%26assetKey%3DAS%253A453635789332484%25401485166608763&usg=AOvVaw2mcrwtkKlbiktayDD7ngEv)